# Degree of the reflection map: $r_i: S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

I tried to compute the degree of the reflection map. I'm wondering if I'm right ?

> Let the reflection map,
> $$
>   r_i: S^{n} \longrightarrow S^{n}, (x_1, ..., x_i,...,x_{n+1}) \longrightarrow (x_1, ..., -x_i, ..., x_{n+1})
> $$
> Compute the degree of that mapping.

Well, because $S^{n}$ is compact and connected and $r_i$ is a mapping between two manifold of the same dimension, the degree of that mapping is the same as the local degree of that mapping evaluated at any regular value $y \in S^{n}$ by the theorem stating the independance of the local degree with respect to the regular value,

$$
  \deg{(r_i)} = \deg{(r_i ; y)}
$$

So the first step is to choose a regular value of $S^{n}$.

Because the reflexion $r_i$ is across any plane of equation $x_i = 0$, we can choose in particular a reflexion that is NOT across the plane $\pi \equiv x_1 = 0$.

The point $x^{\ast} = (1, 0, 0, ...)$ is therefore a fixed point of that reflexion : $r_i(x^{\ast}) = x^{\ast}$ where $i \neq 0$.

Then, because $x^{\ast}$ is a fixed point, $r_i$ is a one-to-one mapping in $x^{\ast}$ and then the differential,

$$
  d(r_i)_{x^{\ast}}: T_{x^{\ast}}S^{n} \rightarrow T_{r(x^{\ast})}S^{n} = T_{x^{\ast}}S^{n}
$$

is an isomorphism. In particular, $d(r_i)_{x^{\ast}}$ is a mapping onto then $x^{\ast}$ is a **regular point**.

We compute the degree in the corresponding regular value (which is the same as that regular point),

$$
  \deg{(r_i ; r_i(x^{\ast}))} = \text{sign}(\det(d(r_i)_{x^{\ast}}))
$$

We see that,

$$
  d(r_i)_{x^{\ast}} = 
  \begin{pmatrix} 
   1 & ... & ... & ... & ... &... & 0 \\
   ... & ... & ... & ... & ... &... & 0 \\
   ... & ... & ... & -1 & ... & ... & 0 \\
   ... & ... & ... & ... & ... &... & 0 \\
   0 & ... & ... & ... & ... &... & 1
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

And,

$$
  \text{det}(d(r_i)_{x^{\ast}}) = \prod_{i=1}^{n+1} a_{ii} = -1 
$$

Therefore,

$$
\deg{(r_i)} = \deg{(r_i ; r_i(x^{\ast}))} = \text{sign}(-1) = -1
$$

The degree of the reflection map is $-1$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: If you use `\text{deg}` rather than `\deg`, then the software will not automatically give you context-dependent spacing by which the space to the right of $\deg$ in $\deg f$ differs from that in $\deg(f).$ That is among the reasons why `\deg` is standard usage.